# Programatically get audit log for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, audit-log-reports

Which libraries or API to use to access/download audit log reports from a SharePoint Online environment.

Is there a way to download the whole audit log from SharePoint online environment?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides information to pull data from the Office 365/Azure AD audit logs. You can find more information at [Office 365 Management Activity API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference).

It's important to note that the SharePoint Online site audit logs have been removed from SharePoint Online. There were no APIs to pull data from them.